# To run VBA macros after every 5 days

Tags: excel, vba, automation

As you see that all below mentioned Macros calling schedules are linked with one another. However I would like to run the first **Sub Button1_Click()** macro after every 5 days. Currently the application.Ontime does not increase after 23 hours. Can someone please advise how to i setup the first macro **Sub Button1_Click()** (Hence rest of the macros are linked with Button1 they will run automatically) to run after every 5 days automatically.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Part1"
End Sub

Sub Part1()
    Call DeleteFiles
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "Part2"
End Sub

Sub Part2()
    Call CopyFiles_r2
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:55"), "Part3"
End Sub

Sub Part3()
    Call MakeFolders
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:40"), "Part4"
End Sub


Sub Part4()
    Call moveMatchedFilesInAppropriateFolders
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:55"), "Part5"
End Sub

Sub Part5()
    Call OrganizeFilesByFileType
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:35"), "Part1"
End Sub
```

I will be thankful

Comment: If you are using excel just as a place to hold code to manipulate files then I'd create the tasks as standalone exe files and then use windows to schedule the tasks to run at appropriate times.  You can't do this with VBA but fortunately there is a new kid on the block, twinBasic, https://twinbasic.com/preview.html which is a VB/VBA replacement which will allow you do do exactly that, and very easily.

Comment: @FreeFlow Maybe this could be done in VBA, but i am just a learner therefore i am not able to write it properly :)   Can you please help how to write standalone.exe so that i can add that in windows scheduler and that hopefully will run after every 5 days at 12:00 Midnight :) Thanks

Comment: You have been given the help you need.  One of the sample project available when you open the twinbasic Ide it to create a standard exe.  You could also look at using VB.Net or C# but this will require you to install Visual Studio.

Comment: Okay Thanks @freeflow let me work on twinbasic.com

Comment: You could also use something like VBS or Powershell, both can be scheduled in task scheduler like exe files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it sort of IS possible, it's just not the BEST way to do something.

First, take all 5 steps and call them all from your workbook module.
Make sure it's set to Workbook_Open Trigger:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    ' > Give you enough time to Pause/Break when you manually open the file.
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    
    ' > Run Series
    Call DeleteFiles                            'Part 1
    Call CopyFiles_r2                           'Part 2
    Call MakeFolders                            'Part 3
    Call moveMatchedFilesInAppropriateFolders   'Part 4
    Call OrganizeFilesByFileType                'Part 5
    
    ' > Close WB
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    
End Sub
```

Next, open your task scheduler:

[image]

Create a new task:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Or whatever...

Here, enter Dir for Excel program and .xlsm file:

[image]

Finally Save!

Limitations:
This may only work when logged in and computer is awake.
There is a way for you to task schedule a login... but that's a lot of work, and your company's security policy may dislike that.
I would suggest you use "run at login" in that case.

---

<

---

**UPDATE:**

The `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` needs to be places in the `ThisWorkbook` Module:

[image]

So now every time I open my workbook, it will say "Hello World"

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for the detail answer, i will check it and will revert

Comment: I have copied and pasted the Sub you have provided in my VBA Pane. At My end it was module6 so I rename the module6 with Workbook_Open   Then i have followed the procedure you suggested of Task schedule.. Finally it opened the correct workbook but the code is not running i.e. it does not execute just opening the file

Comment: Ah, no. You need to place it in the "ThisWorkbook" module. I will update my answer.